# How to catch Boolean returned value of a method from another method and do some operations?

Tags: java, spring, return

I have two methods in the same class.

```
public Boolean pinValidation(Obj 1, Obj 2){

// Here i have to return Boolean true or false
 boolean status = false;
 /..... Some Code segments goes here .. 
 return true;
}

public Payment checkPayment(Obj 1, Obj2){
 pinValidation();

// Here if the return value of first method true
 if(status == true){
    //set of instructions
   }
}
```

What i want to how to catch above return boolean values and do the operation?
any help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do something like:

```
boolean status = pinValidation();
```

Or you could simplify by using:

```
if (pinValidation()) {
    //set of instructions
}
```

Note: use `boolean` everywhere. No need to mix `boolean` and `Boolean`.

Comment: if i use like this will it be wrong? 

if(status == true){
    pinValidation();
}

Comment: No, it won't be wrong. However, the Java idiom would be `if (status) { ... }`, ie. we don't compare to `true`.

Comment: @L.Anush Yes it will be wrong.  Do it the way dave suggests.

Answer (score 0):

**First at all**, you need to be aware on how to manage conditionals, so let me add some of code about conditionals:

```
 if (true) { //if the  condition is true, the code below will be executed 
   // code to execute here
 }
```

Then you don't need to evaluate someBooleanValue == true simply you need to call it.

```
 if (pinValidation()) {
   // code to execute here
 }
```

**Second**, you need to know differences between **Boolean** that is an Object which will help you with some methods and **boolean** that is primitive type and saves a lot of memory then you can use what one is better based on your problem.

Comment: if i change like this? 

 if(status == true){ pinValidation(); } Anything wrong?

Comment: As I described in my answer, you should put status as boolean directly in the condition  if (status) {...} nothing is wrong but it looks no sense because call pinValidation() method for validation has no sense but if you tell me that pinValidation() does some change of object values or logic, it's OK, on my concerns this will depend of your issue.